# Trying to setup a git hook for Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins

How do I set up a GIT Hook so that whenever a change is pushed to the repo, it triggers a Jenkins build.

Here's what I did,
- Enabled trigger on push in build
- Add a git hook http://test.corp.test.com:8080/github-webhook/
on push

But its not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Is Jenkins running on the same network as test.corp.test.com is running?

Comment: yes it is. good question

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the git hook that's currently set up, as well as the JSON payload when/if that link gets hit?

Answer (score 0):

If you can post the request/response that gives a view on the JSON payload it can help debug it further.
We had one issue before it was with GITHub OAuth integration , it was returning as HTTP 500 error code and it is solved after enabled read access on the anonymous user.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the trigger on push in Jenkins, I set up the Jenkins job allow Trigger Builds remotely, and then set in my post-receive githook a call to the Jenkins REST to trigger my build - something like:

```
curl "http://${JENKINS_SERVER}/buildByToken/buildWithParameters?job=${jobname}&token=${JOB_TOKEN}${NAME_PARAM}&RepoName=${userRepo}&BranchName=${userBranch}&DevEmail=${userEmail}"
```